# testing $state.reload.then() in an angular application where $state is from an AngularJS app

Tags: angular, angularjs, ts-jest

I have a use case wherein `$state` from AngularJS is getting used in Angular

```
// In Angular app
this.$state.reload().then(() => {
          // perform some action in Angular app
        });
```

This code works as expected. Using jest, the `$state.reload` can be tested to have been called. However, the actions performed after `$state.reload` is complete also need to be tested. Is there a way to achieve this?